# Adicionar hashtag da tag principal no "Compartilhar link"

Tags: novo-recurso

Costumo divulgar algumas postagens minhas no twitter usando o link "Compartilhar link" que fica abaixo de todas perguntas e respostas ativas.

No entanto notei que o Stack Overflow em Português tem uma página do Twitter [@StackOverflowPT](https://twitter.com/StackOverflowPT), sempre que o BOT (acho que é um robô) compartilha algo ele coloca a hash com a tag "principal" da pergunta, por exemplo:

- https://twitter.com/StackOverflowPT/status/699714104890671104

Vejam que aparece `#javascript` que se refere a tag "principal".

Gostaria de sugeria algumas coisas, ao clicar em *Compartilhar link*:

- No Twitter, Facebook e G+ automaticamente aparece `#{tag principal}`
- No Twitter automaticamente aparece `@StackOverflowPT` para que possamos "interagir" com o perfil do twitter da comunidade SOpt.

> Sugestão extra (criar shortlinks) em [Add hashtag with tag of question in 'share' before posting](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/275752/198279)

Comment: Oi @Guilherme Nascimento! Aproveitando a sua pergunta: é possível (e correto, ético, bem-visto, etc..) copiar o link que aparece no caixa *Compartilhar Link* e compartilhar em outras redes sociais, por exemplo: LinkedIn? Já que a `#{tag principal}` pode ser acrescentada manualmente, há algum problema em fazer isso?

Comment: @Gomeiro muitos tem essa duvida, as postagens nos sites da rede SE são escritos sob a licença [CreativeCommons](https://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/3.0/) recomendo que leia estes links: http://meta.pt.stackoverflow.com/q/4167/3635 e http://meta.pt.stackoverflow.com/q/2212/3635

Comment: Muito obrigado! Acho que a minha maior dúvida era se o compartilhamento é "bem-visto" pela comunidade e, pelos links, eu vi que sim.

Comment: @Gomiero esse é um grande problema, o sistema é feito para compartilhar mesmo, até copiar, por isso usamos a licença CC-by-sa-3.0, mas tem muito usuário que não entende isso e começa a pensar que quem compartilha esta tirando proveito, sendo que na verdade compartilhar os links ajuda em muito a comunidade, tem muita gente diferente de você que não entende o funcionamento da comunidade e começa a inventar as "próprias regras" de certo e errado, quando na verdade elas devem ter atitudes que nem a sua que é perguntar, **parabéns** você é um ótimo usuário, pois na duvida você perguntou ;)

Comment: Novamente, Muito Obrigado pelas dicas! Já ganhei a medalha 'Anunciador' hoje, por um post que fiz no Facebook :-)